# vmware workstation - How can you boot from CD?

Tags: vmware-workstation

On VMware workstation, when I boot a VM I see a screen appear for booting CD but it doesn't last  long. I definitely try hitting F2 when I see it, and i'm a very fast guy, still no luck.

How do I do it?

[image]

I have heard of an option to power on to BIOS but I don't see it. I see VM..power on to firmware.

Comment: "Power on to firmware" is the new name for "Power on to BIOS" since some VMs now use EFI instead of BIOS.  BIOS is a type of firmware.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right to act as soon as it starts, but don't just hit a key. You have to mouse click to enter the VM, and then hit the key (F2 for BIOS or ESC for boot menu)    F12 for network boot though I haven't used network boot.

When the virtual machine starts, the mouse cursor changes from an arrow to a hand cursor, but you are not in the virtual machine unless you click, and then the cursor will disappear. Then, it will respond to key presses.

You can also edit the vmx file of the virtual machine, and add the line `bios.bootDelay = "15000"` (15000 milliseconds is 15 seconds but you can change it to whatever) and you get another screen that offers the same keys and a 15 second delay to hit them. Of course, you have to click first. You might want to shorten it from 15 seconds. But if you've been missing it you might appreciate the screen being there for 15 seconds, then change it once you've figured out how to do it.

When practicing you might want to shutdown and power up, rather than restart, so it's a bit clearer when it is powering up, though restarting is OK.

Another option is "power on to firmware", try it, it goes to the BIOS. It's in the menu when right clicking a VM, or in the VM menu at the top. And in some versions of vmware workstation it's "power on to BIOS".  In my version it's "power on to firmware" but it goes to the BIOS

Oddly, while in an ubuntu VM, F2 and ESC don't bring up the BIOS,   choosing "power on to firmware" does. (or "power on to bios" in other VMware workstation versions).

**Added**
  jamesdlin points out in comment

"Power on to firmware" is the new name for "Power on to BIOS" since some VMs now use EFI instead of BIOS. BIOS is a type of firmware.

Comment: A good virtual machine to experiment with is a Win or Bart PE ISO.  It restarts quickly so if you miss it you can restart within a few seconds, and try again. I was experimenting with an ubuntu VM but when missing a key for some reason it wasn't quick to restart.  And even when it was, it kept bringing up a grub menu.

Comment: also ubuntu for some reason when you hit F2 it runs grub. Whether boot delay or not But boot to firmware gets it to the BIOS.

Comment: Note there is no power on to firmware option in workstation player (v12). You prbably need to upgrade to pro.

Comment: 2018 and we still have to deal with the stupidity of whoever thought ESC was a good key to bring the boot menu

Comment: @Dan the same guy that thought "keyboard not detected, press any key to continue" was a good idea!

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following to make your job easier.

> To make it easier to access the BIOS setup screen, edit the virtual
>   machine's configuration (.vmx) and add or edit one of these options:
>
> bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"
>
> This forces entry to the BIOS setup at startup.
>
> bios.bootDelay = "xxxx"
>
> This adds a delay to the initial POST screen, showing it for longer
>   and giving you more time to access the BIOS setup, where xxxx is the
>   number of milliseconds to show the POST screen. (There are 1000
>   milliseconds in a second.) The maximum value for the boot delay is
>   10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds.

**Note:** *Other [documentation](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16876/how-to-increase-the-vmware-boot-screen-delay/) indicates the actually maximum delay is 20 seconds or 20000 milliseconds.*

[Source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004129)

Once you have access to the BIOS setup you can change the boot order permanently by doing the following.

> Switch to the Boot tab, and change the ordering of the items by
>   pressing the “+” key to move items up on the list, and the “-” key to
>   move items down the list.
>
> [image] [image]

VMWare’s BIOS does not allow you to boot to a USB device, but you can
get around that limitation, by using the [PLoP Boot Manager](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/).  The source tutorial continues to explain how to actually boot to a USB device in more detail but that isn't what you are trying to do.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16876/how-to-increase-the-vmware-boot-screen-delay/)

Comment: When I started to write and submit this answer barlop's answer was a single sentence.

Comment: Your answer still adds value. Fundamentally though my error was not clicking.

Comment: When I add that force.. line I get an error  http://i.imgur.com/l5igfXw.png   "dictionary problem".  This is the relevant part of my vmx file http://i.imgur.com/ZThX3BQ.png

Comment: Most of this comes straight from VMWare's own website.  You don't indicate which which version of VMWare Workstation or VMWare Player you are using though.  The knowlegebase article claims it basically supports all versions though.  I won't be able to research it myself further until tonight.

Comment: VMWare Workstation 11.0.0 build-2305329

Comment: Also (and yes I can see your source is the vmware site)  It's not correct that the max is 10 seconds. You can successfully set 20 seconds for example, I tested it.

Comment: @barlop - I will get back with you.  The documentation indicates this information is correct.  If you find the error, before I find it, I will accept the edit to correct it though.

Comment: you might not run into the dictionary error, but it'll be interesting to see one way or the other. As to the timing, the doc is definitely wrong on that one.

Comment: You said you'd get back to this. Did you run into the dictionary error too?

Comment: @barlop - No; I didn't have the same error

Comment: @barlop Do you perhaps have multiple occurrences of `bios.forceSetupOnce` in your `.vmx` file?  Really you should just use "Power on to Firmware" and not hand-edit the `.vmx` file.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way without changing bios setup:

Add the line bios.bootOrder = "cdrom,floppy,hdd,ethernet1" in the vmx file of the VM.

Answer (score -3):

Simply stated, in most instances it is faster to rebuild an entire host than to expect you can hist escape or F2 in the millisecond they allow for this to occur.

Comment: -1 well, that's not very simply stated, 'cos it's not clear whether you're trying to suggest that rebuilding an entire host is an alternative