# Unable to boot from ISO in an already installed guest of VMware 12

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have VMware 12. I have a Windows VM that works well. Now I need on the same VM to boot from an ISO instead of the guest image. But it never goes for the ISO and always boots with the guest image.

Any idea of how I can do that?

I have read https://www.isunshare.com/blog/how-to-set-vmware-boot-from-iso-image-file/ with no success (in my VMware I don't even see `Power on BIOS`, I only see `Power on Firmware`)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with VMware Workstation 12, but are you perhaps using UEFI boot? Does the ISO require Legacy?

Comment: Is the CD/DVD drive set to "Connect at power on"? ([step 8](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002) in this tutorial)? Are you sure the ISO is set to be bootable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vmware workstation - How can you boot from CD?](https://superuser.com/questions/940427/vmware-workstation-how-can-you-boot-from-cd)

Answer (score 1):

"Power On to BIOS" was renamed to "Power On to Firmware" so that it could apply to either BIOS or UEFI firmwares. Old instructions about "Power On to BIOS" otherwise should still work.